# Submitting form with ajax in Yii

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, yii

I’m stuck and any help will be appreciated.

I have a form with an ajax link to submit.

The form link is the following:

```
<div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::Button('SUBMIT AJAX',array('onclick'=>'send();')); ?> 
</div>
```

the function `send` contains the following:

```
function send()
 {

   var data=$("#comment-form").serialize();



  $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
    url: '<?php echo Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl("post/ajax"); ?>',
   data:data,
    success:function(data){
                alert(data); 
              },
    error: function(data) { // if error occured
         alert("Error occured.please try again");
         alert(data);
    },

  dataType:'html'
  });

}
```

And the ajax action in controller contains the following:

```
public function actionAjax() {

$model=new Comment;
if(isset($_POST['Comment']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Comment'];

            if($model->validate())
            {
           //$model->save();

           print_r($_REQUEST);
           return;
            }
        }
        $this->render('comment',array('model'=>$model));

 }
}
?>
```

the `print_r` output shows that all fields are filled:

```
Array
(
    [Comment] => Array
        (
            [post_id] => 2
            [author] => sss
            [email] => sss@dldksl.com
            [url] => http://www.mysite.com
            [content] => sksjdjh 
            [status] => 1
        )

)
```

When I uncomment the `$model->save()`, I get integrity error  `post_id cannot be null`.

It seems that my model is empty,  how can I set model to `$_REQUEST`?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you updating record or creating new record?

Comment: Do a `print_r($model->attributes)` to make sure it has the correct values.

Comment: I did print_r($model-> attributes)  and then post_id is empty !  do you know why ?   @Pitchinnate

Comment: @sanfisa. Pls answer my question too

Comment: I'm creating a new record comment,  the post_id is automatically filled, it is the parent_id  @kumar_v

Comment: ok. Better you assign manually like `$model->post_id = $_POST["comments"]["post_id"]`

Comment: You probably have no rule set for the `post_id` attribute. See this article for more information: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/161/understanding-safe-validation-rules/#hh2

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
                                  'id'=>'customer-form-guest',
                                  'enableClientValidation'=>true,
                                  'clientOptions'=>array(
                                  'validateOnSubmit'=>true,

                                        'afterValidate' => 'js:function(form, data, hasError) { 
              if(hasError) {
                  return false;
      }
              else
              {
         // return true;  it will submit default way
                   ajaxSubmitHappen(form, data, hasError); and it will submit by ajax function 
               }
           }',
'htmlOptions'=>array('role'=>"form"))); ?>
```

now ajax sub,mit function

```
function  ajaxSubmitHappen(form, data, hasError)
{
    if(!hasError)
{

                                 $.ajax({

                                    "type":"POST",
                                    "url":"<?php echo $url;  ?>",
                                    "data":form.serialize(),
                                    "success":function(data){
                                     },

                                  });
     }
      else
    { 
       alert('error');
     }
```

by this way you can submit the form via ajax....